# Count day SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm currently trying to solve a problem i have.

```
   | ID | Op | Object | STATE | Timestamp |
   | 01 | 1  | A      |   1   | 01-02-2016|
   | 02 | 1  | A      |   2   | 04-02-2016|
   | 03 | 1  | A      |   1   | 10-02-2016|
   | 04 | 1  | A      |   3   | 01-02-2016|
   | 05 | 2  | A      |   2   | 02-02-2016|
   | 06 | 3  | A      |   1   | 05-02-2016|
   | 07 | 3  | A      |   2   | 10-11-2016|
```

I need to write a SQL that return the count of days that an object past at STATE 2.
Example, the object A, stay from 04-02 to 10-02 at STATE 2 + 02-02 to 05-02 and from 10-11 to TODAY so 6 day + 3 day + 4 day.

```
  SQL return 13
```

Currently make it by code but i need it in an SQL extract and i don't know how to proceed. Is that possible by SQL?

Thank you

Comment: I don't understand this table. On 01-02-2016 object A switched to state 1 (record 01) and state 3 (record 04)? From 02-02-2016 to 03-02-2016 it had state 1 (from record 01) and state 2 (from record 05). On 04-02-2016 it had state 2 twice (from records 05 and 02) and on 05-02-2016 it had state 2 (from record 02) and state 1 (from record 06). So an object has multiple states and you can only determine which and how many states by ordering by ID and looking up overlapping date ranges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want `lead()` along with aggregation and date logic:

```
select object,
       sum(case when state = 2 then datediff(day, timestamp, coalesce(next_timestamp, getdate()) )
                else 0
           end) as days_state_2
from (select t.*,
             lead(timestamp) over (partition by object order by timestamp) as next_timestamp
      from t
     ) t
group by object;
```

Or, you can move the filtering condition to the outer `select`:

```
select object,
       sum(datediff(day, timestamp, coalesce(next_timestamp, getdate()) )) as days_state_2
from (select t.*,
             lead(timestamp) over (partition by object order by timestamp) as next_timestamp
      from t
     ) t
where state = 2
group by object;
```

Comment: Thank you, didn't know about Lead() and it work fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
select object,
       sum(datediff(day, timestamp, coalesce(next_timestamp, getdate()) )) as days_state_2
from (select *,
             lead(timestamp) over (partition by object order by timestamp) as next_timestamp
      from #b
     ) t
where state = 2
group by object;
```

Comment: Thank you, didn't know about Lead() and it work fine.